# Read multiple images from a post Facebook with the Graph feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Through a lack of good documentation of the Facebook Graph I need your help.

I use this piece of php code to get posts form a Facebook page:

```
file_get_contents_curl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/$pageFBID/feed?fields=full_picture,message,story,created_time,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)&access_token=".$token);
```

This call works fine but I want to get all the images, instead of only one. Does someone know how?

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly found the soluction. You have to add the 'parameter' *attachments* to the url to get all the images and other media attached to the post, in a large size.

```
file_get_contents_curl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/$pageFBID/feed?fields=full_picture,attachments,message,story,created_time,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)&access_token=".$token);
```

Comment: Did one search in google and this came up first in the list and it worked like a charm! Thanks for sharing!